# Django admin, models list show up but are not clickable/editable

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django admin page that show my models list but instead of showing links with buttons for adding and editing model instances, everything is disabled. Only black texts with no links and no buttons.

I'm logged in as super admin and the admin page show correctly the models that have been registered in admin.py.

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

**EDIT:**

After looking in the Django template that render the admin dashboard, I can see that there is a condition there that cause the rendering of a plain text instead of the desired link:

```
{% if model.admin_url %}
    <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
{% else %}
    <th scope="row">{{ model.name }}</th>
{% endif %}
```

Any idea why the model.admin_url would be None in my situation?

Also, the urls that are supposed to be used in that admin page are not working:
for exemple: /admin/auth/user/ give me a 404 error... This is probably why the links are not rendered... I'm now looking for the WHY...

Comment: are you getting any JavaScript errors in your web console?

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG=False` in your `settings.py`? Does it work when you set it to `True`?

Comment: No Javascript errors in firebug.

Comment: It's on a prod server and DEBUG=False. I can't really change it to test. On my dev server I try DEBUG=False and True and it does not matter, the problem is never present.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which I resolved by adding a admin.py file to my app. Instead of now registering the models with admin in my models.py file I do it in the admin.py file.

After restarting everything, it works now!